# How to structure data in MVVM

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to build my first WP7 app and I'm a bit confused about how to do organize data. My data is on an XML file and I have three kinds of data to represent on the device: sales by country, by year, and by city.
I've seen some examples and I think to build 3 classes like `CountryViewModel`, `YearViewModel`, and `CityViewModel` on which I have the single fields exposed as property.

Then I think to add a MainViewModel to handle the rest, but in the examples I've seen in `MainViewModel` there is a reference to a single `itemViewModel`, then should I create `MainCountryViewModel`, `MainYearViewModel`, and `MainCityViewModel`?

Can anyone point me to the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an interesting question. Here's what I think is right:

- ViewModels should be structured around the Views - they should hold the data in a format that is "friendly" and "convenient" for the views to use.
- Behind these ViewModels, you can structure the persistent Models in a format that is convenient for loading and saving - or for sending over the wire.
- The reason the samples mostly have a MainViewModel with a list of ItemViewModel's is because most of the samples just show a main window with a ListBox of items
- If you look at CodePlex, then you should be able to find quite a few samples with more complicated ViewModel structures - e.g. http://4square.codeplex.com, http://mahtweetswp7.codeplex.com, http://gasmileage.codeplex.com, ...

So... for your app: I think if it fits with your UI, then you should definitely create a MainViewModel and let it have the three properties of observable lists of Country, Year and City-ViewModels.

Comment: cool, thank you very much for your useful and complete answer !

Comment: To reinforce and agree the first bullet point. It is helpful to think of the VM as the view of the model, not the domain model as presented to the view.